# Online tool without login to create animated GIF

Tags: animation, gif, tools

This request is addressed to all users in order to create animated gifs that can be placed on one of the **stackexchange** sites (I use a lot of **TeX.SE**.) when I would like to better explain a question or an answer.

For example, to be able to document that my pdf is not compilable, I would like **to register with an online tool to convert it as a .gif** (a short animate image of 10 sec (max)), without having a software or add-ons or other installed on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THere are a few commonly-used tools for this - I've used both of these repeatedly:

https://www.onlineconverter.com/mp4-to-gif

https://ezgif.com/

I prefer EZ GIF overall.

Comment: Dunno mate - I upvoted you to balance out!

Comment: Concordo con il mio amico, ma purtroppo non essendo l'autore di quel voto in basso, non so come rispondere al tuo commento sulla mia risposta!

Comment: No sir - worked years ago for a US subsidiary to an Italian tech firm (SAES Getters) and picked up a very little, and traveled in Italy years ago (architecture student) so 
ho preso un po 'di italiano - but mostly... google translate is my friend!

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh LOL I use deepl translator :-)

Comment: La traduzione dall'inglese all'italiano è molto migliore in Deepl?

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. In fact, on TeX.SE. I have communication problems sometimes.